# Django Model ForeignKey on_delete=models.SET()

Tags: python, django-models

sample model:

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False)

class Book(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET(func))
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
  publisher = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
```

if I deleted an author from `Author`, how could I set the ForeignKey `Book.author` to that author's `name`?
could anyone help me out? thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't. A `ForeignKey` simply refers to an object, by storing its id, or another field. There is *referential integrity*, so normally the database will reject such update.

Comment: What does that mean "how could I set the ForeignKey Book.author to that author's name?"???

Comment: It might be better to add a field to the `Author` with `removed` that is a boolean field, and thus "soft kill" the `Author` object.

Comment: thank you @WillemVanOnsem however if I'm facing a situation that I have to "hard kill" the `Author`, are there any alternative ways to keep track of the author's name of each book? sorry for asking some silly questions currently self-learning Python and Django :)